How to forward stripe events from local CI to testing endpoint on stripe dashboard?
I have integrated the Stripe dispute concept in my application and deployed the webhook. Now I want to publish a dispute created event from my local CLI by forwarding events to my staging environment webhook, like:
➜ ./stripe listen --forward-to https://myapp.stage.app/stripe/webhook/event

As soon as I do this, of course, a new webhook signing secret is published on the console:
A newer version of the Stripe CLI is available, please update to: v1.19.4
> Ready! You are using Stripe API Version [2020-03-02]. 
Your webhook signing secret is whsec_local_secret (^C to quit)

Is there a way I can forward events using a custom webhook signing secret?
I didn't find any other way I can test the dispute integration as we cannot mark payments as disputed from the dashboard for testing purposes.

That's the expected behavior when stripe listen will always generate a new signing secret, and you would need to use that value in your localhost server.
It's a limitation to not be able to reusing a signing secret, unfortunately, but it shouldn't be a blocker where you can always update that value to your server.

This can be a comment, not an answer.
